# Cannot login after removing DC role

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, remote-desktop

I have removed the Domain Controller role from my Windows Server 2008 R2. Now I cannot login remotely any more with the Administrator account, neither using the username "\Administrator", nor "Administrator".

Does anyone know how to get onto this server now?

Comment: Have you tried <COMPUTER-NAME>\administrator? Do you only have remote access to the machine?

Comment: Yes, I only have remote access to the machine but my data center provider offers something like a remote VGA access. Do you think this could help me further?

Comment: I have tried COMPUTER-NAME\Administrator, without success.

Comment: Time for Disaster Recovery...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the machine is still a member of a domain (i.e. if you did not remove the last and only DC from the domain), you should be able to log in with DOMAIN\administrator and the domainadmin credentials.

If it *was* the last DC of a domain or you can't use the domain admin account for some other reason, you need to use the "MACHINE\Administrator" user and the password you've specified for "Directory Service Recovery Mode" during promotion.

If this password is lost, reset it by using a `ntpasswd` [boot disk or live CD](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) and try again.

Comment: Works, even when only using \Administrator. Thanks!